# Openshift/original - create image based on Wildfly

Tags: docker, openshift, wildfly, dockerfile, openshift-origin

For Openshift: How can I create a docker image based on Wildfly?

This is the Dockerfile is used:

```
FROM openshift/wildfly-101-centos7
# Install example app on wildfy
COPY target/ROOT.war /opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
# Default Startup by Wildfly, so no CMD needed.
# Expose ports we are interested in. Via the run I can use these
EXPOSE 8080 443
# CMD - use the default wildfly start command
```

After pushing the image, openshift gives the error:

> This is an S2I WildFly v10.1.0 Final centos base image responsible for
>   consuming a JEE project and deploying it onto WildFly application
>   server. To use it, install S2I:
>   https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image .

Should I use another image? The jboss/wildfly?

This is what I did to create, tag and push the image.

- Mvn clean install --- to create the ROOT.war
- docker build -t project/application .
- docker tag project/application registry.etc.com
- docker push registry.etc.com
- oc new-app mynewapplication

Q2: How can I publish the 8080 port ... or is this done by Openshift?

Comment: They typically use S2I for this sort of thing but you may be able to do something similar to a pipeline. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/dev_tutorials/binary_builds.html#binary-builds-pipeline-binary-artifacts. Also, you can use a maven plugin or run docker by hand and then push the resulting image to hub.docker.com and use it for a binary build. So, I think is to take the image you create and push to hub.docker and then do `oc new-build --docker-image=myimage --name=myname` or something like that.

Comment: See example of using Wildfly S2I builder with OpenShift in the free eBook OpenShift for Developers at https://www.openshift.com/for-developers/

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton - Thank you! S2I is a quick solution. In this case I wanted to use a Dockerfile without S2I.

Comment: @K.Nicholas - Thank you. I tried the FROM wildfly:latest. In my case, I had to prepend it with jboss.

Comment: In case you are not aware S2I is available outside of OpenShift if the issue is you want to build images separately. See https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** Q1**: S2I is a good way of working when you don't want to think about creating images / containers. The standard Openshift/Wildfly images can be used for S2I.

When you want to work with a docker client with Openshift as a Container As A Service (CAAS) provider you will need another Wildfly image.

This Dockerfile will get you going. You can of course improve it with limiting the user permissions, etc.

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
COPY target/ROOT.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
# CMD - use the default wildfly default start command
```

*** Q2**: Via the Openshift Console you can add a **route** to explicitly do the port mapping of your ports. Just select via the Console the Applications > Routes. I used the default settings with the 443 secure port.

You should NOT use 8080. In my experience I use Openshift always with a secure 443 port.

**CAAS OVERVIEW**: For your convenience you can find an [overview of the steps for CAAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50533145/3143823). 
Any improvements or further suggestions are very welcom!